# Verb misuse question

Tags: verbs

I've come across a few references in written and spoken American English along the lines of "She feared him into staying home," or, "The new development feared them to upgrade their defenses." I understand that the usage is not formally correct, and that "scared" is a much more appropriate verb choice.  I can imagine this phenomenon happening with other verbs, e.g. "They worried the poor chap to move out."

Can anyone explain what it is that makes this incorrect, i.e. what is the general grammar rule being bent?

Comment: This is very similar to the incorrect dialectical use of "learn". E.g., *"After supper she got out her book and learned me about Moses and the Bulrushers"* from *Huckleberry Finn.*

Comment: Lots of stative verbs, like _fear_ or _know_, have inchoative and causative verbs from different stems, like _scare_ (which also relates to _be scared_) or _learn_ and _teach_ (with separate verbs for each sense).

Answer (score 1):

English has the concepts of verbs having *active* or *passive* voice.

In the active voice, the grammatical subject (nominative noun) is the 'actor' or 'doer', and the grammatical object (accusative noun) is the 'patient' or the one that the action operates on.

For example, in "Bruce kicked the bull", Bruce does the kicking and the bull is subjected to the kicking.

In the passive voice, the nominative is the patient and and the accusative is the actor.

For example, in "Bruce was kicked by the bull", Bruce is now subjected to the kicking, and the bull is the one that does the kicking.

Some languages have the concept of 'middle voice'. I don't recall this being highlighted during my school days, but it helps to explain the problem you bring up.

When a verb is in the 'middle voice', the nominative is in some sense both actor and patient.

For example, in "Bruce feared the bull", Bruce is the one who is doing the fearing, but you could also say that the one who becomes afraid (the 'patient' of the fearing) is also Bruce.

The obvious objection is to argue that "fear" is in the active voice because, following the above constructions, we can say that *the bull was feared*. Nevertheless, with *kicking*, the kicker is not intrinsically equated with the one being kicked. On the other hand, when one 'does' some *fearing* (so to speak), the one who got frightened is the same person - the object of the fear isn't the one said to be frightened.

*Fear* and *worry* are both 'middle voice' verbs in this sense. The one who fears or worries is the one who is afraid or worried. The actor-patient link is so deep with these words that saying "she feared him ..." doesn't carry the sense that she made *him* afraid. When someone tries to wrench *fear*, *worry* or any other 'middle voice' verb into the active (or passive) voice as your example tries to do, the resulting sentence sounds awkward.

This isn't the case with the word "scared". If Bruce scared the bull, Bruce is the one doing the scaring, and the one ending up scared is the bull (not Bruce). Even "Bruce is scared" doesn't necessarily equate actor and patient - Bruce might be the patient, but he doesn't have to be the 'actor' doing the scaring (the bull might be the one scaring Bruce). So since *scare* is an active/passive voice verb and not a 'middle voice' verb, it can properly replace "fear" and "worry" (grammatically) in your examples.

Comment: The question hinges on the acceptability of the expression 'V someone into doing something'. This scared him. This worried him. This scared him into leaving. ??/*This worried him into leaving.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Same answer. We don't normally speak of 'fearing' someone into doing anything. If you wanted to express that idea, you might speak of 'scaring' them into it.

Answer (score 0):

The verb "to fear" is unaccusative. It's action therefore operates on the subject (the theme) rather than the object (patient)

Thus in

"I fear the dark", the action of the verb operates on "I",

Whereas in

"I hit the man" the action of the verb operates on the object.

Comment: The question queries more generally the acceptability of the expression 'V someone into doing something'. This scared him. This worried him. This scared him into leaving. ??/*This worried him into leaving.